# Adding Steam & Civ 5 To My Lap Top While Maintaining It On My Desktop Machine?

Tags: civilization-5

I recently acquired a ASUS notebook (convertible) and would like to know if I can load Steam and play the game on it when not at home.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to play the game on your notebook or do you want to play the game on your desktop and control it from your notebook? The content says the former, the title says the latter.

Comment: Just download Steam, and the game, and play. Steam Cloud will automatically synchronize save data between the two machines.

Comment: @ardaozkal And the answer to both is yes. I love home streaming.

Comment: @Studoku Edit: Ohh, I got it now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes just install steam. 
Login, then restore civ 5 from a backup you had created from your other machine or download it again.

(Cannot play the same game on both machines simultaneously with out more effort)

Comment: And would not be legal to play simultaneously :). SInce that would mean 2 ppl are playing.